# How to prepare a fortran module from a C header file?

Tags: c, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I have this pure C file with 6 functions that I want to make available for fortran programmers:

http://tinyfiledialogs.sourceforge.net

Could C to Fortran "Import" work ?

Should I simply prepare something like a Fortran header file instead ?

I realise that my C code is using several Unix or Windows C header files, and this will complicate the conversion. But surely offering the equivalent of a Fortran header for 6 C functions must be achievable.

```
char const * tinyfd_inputBox (
    char const * const aTitle ,
    char const * const aMessage ,
    char const * const aDefaultInput ) ; 
   // the returned value is a static array
```

edit: I am starting to realize that modules are actually compiler-dependent.
Maybe I should instead prepare a makefile that would produce both the C object file and the fortran module to use it.

Comment: If you want your question answered show the code.  Not a link to some well-dodgy, off-SO, darknet site where angels fear to tread.  But before you do consider your questions topicality -- can C to Fortran translation work ?  Of course it can, but what do you mean ?  Can you translate C to Fortran (I don't know), is there a program to translate from C to Fortran (yes, there are such programs, they are all laughable, and tool recommendations are off-topic).

Comment: There's a whole tag for binding C in fortran, you might want to check out [tag:fortran-iso-c-binding].

Comment: It is not necessary to use `code highlighting` for all words that happen to be also tags. It actually harms reading the text. Use it for code (variables, function names...). You can sometimes use `[tag:tag_name]` but don't overuse it.

Comment: Compiled modules are indeed compiler (and perhaps version) dependent, but the source module file is not, so as you say simply adding a build rule to your makefile and distributing the fortran source file should address this.

Answer (score 1):

If your aim is to make life easy for fortran programmers and help them to use your C code directly in their program then you probably want to look at generating fortran modules that provide *interfaces*. These are somewhat similar to your example header in that they define the routine type and the required inputs and outputs.

I'm not particularly experienced in this so I won't give a specific example here but I'll refer you to [this site](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Generating+C+Interfaces). Another useful source of information would be to look at how other packages do this, for example [netcdf](https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf-fortran) and [PETSc](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Sys/UsingFortran.html).

Comment: Please feel free to edit this answer to include an example, I'll try to do this when I get time but it may not be for a while.

Comment: this is exactly my goal: to help the fortran programmers to use my c library.  I want to prepare the fortran module file to allow easy integration in their fortran code, but they will have to compile the C file for their platforms.

Comment: @lalala you may wish to make this more explicit in your original question, it took me a moment to realise this was the question and not "how do I call C from fortran".