# Mixed programming - Including C++ header to Fortran

Tags: c++, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I am trying to use a function from library written in C++ in my program written in Fortran. The C++ library is summarized in one header file so that if you want to use it in another C++ program you only do `#include functions.h` I would like to find out how to do something similar in Fortran.

From my research I've created this minimal viable example:

clib/functions.h:

```
#ifndef ADD_H
#define ADD_H
extern "C"
{
int __stdcall add(int x, int y);
} 
#endif
```

clib/functions.cpp:

```
extern "C"
{
int __stdcall add(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
}
```

cinclude.c

```
#include "clib/functions.h"
```

cinterface.f95:

```
module cinterface
  use,intrinsic::ISO_C_BINDING
  integer(C_INT)::a,b
  interface
    integer(C_INT) function add(a,b) bind(C,name="add")
      use,intrinsic::ISO_C_BINDING
      implicit none
!GCC$ ATTRIBUTES STDCALL :: add
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES STDCALL :: add
      integer(C_INT), value ::a,b
    end function add
  end interface
end module cinterface
```

main.f90

```
 program main
   use cinterface      
   implicit none
   integer :: c
   c = add(1,2)
   write(*,*) c
 end program
```

makefile:

```
FC = gfortran
CC = g++
LD = gfortran
FFLAGS = -c -O2
CFLAGS = -c -O2
OBJ=main.o 
DEP = \
    cinterface.o cinclude.o

.SUFFIXES: .f90 .f95 .c .o
# default rule to make .o files from .f files
.f90.o  : ;       $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $*.f90 -o $*.o
.f95.o  : ;       $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $*.f95 -o $*.o
.c.o  : ;       $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $*.c -o $*.o
%.o: %.mod
#
main.ex: ${DEP} ${OBJ}
    $(LD)  ${DEP}  ${OBJ} -o prog.exe
#
```

When I try to make this project using Cygwin I get a following error:

```
main.o:main.f90:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `add'
main.o:main.f90:(.text+0x13): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `add'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:19: main.ex] Error 1
```

How can I make `add` function in Fortran work?

Comment: You will also need to include the C++ object with the function when linking.  You probably meant that object rather than `cinclude.o`?  [There may be more required but if you try adding that to the link we'll likely be able to help you more.]

Comment: @francescalus I am sorry you mean adding the `clib\functions.h` into makefile or adding `functions.o` crated from `clib\functions.cpp` there? Because in the original problem adding all of the object fiels created from the source files is not possible (or at least not practical)

Comment: Yes, the compiled C++ code will have to available at linking (whether in the executable object or some dynamic means).  The Fortran interface block just says "I promise that there exists a symbol looking like this" - you still need to provide it, and that's the C++ object.

Comment: @francescalus Is there a way to provide Fortran with the information about these "promised symbols" directly from the C++ header?

Comment: Fortran compilers generally don't understand C++, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37673536/3157076) possibly relates to your desire. That's different from your current problem, though: your Fortran interface is already telling you what the C++ header has.

Comment: What does 'nm cinlcude.o' report?  I suspect you have some name mangling of add, perhaps, to add_.  You'll also need to add the VALUE attribute to your Fortran interface for entities 'a' and 'b'.

Comment: @evets `nm cinlcude.o` reports `nm: 'cinlcude.o': No such file`. How can the mangling of add to add_ happen and how can I test that? as for the value attirbute I have suspected that, but it should not make any problems when building the project, should it?

Comment: Value attribute will be necessary I you plan to pass non-array and non-pointer arguments to an interoperable procedure for it to work properly.

Comment: You need the `VALUE` attribute on dummy arguments `a` and `b` and `function add`. Also you need `!GCC$ ATTRIBUTES STDCALL :: add` and throwing in `!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES STDCALL :: add` wouldn't hurt either. The lack of the STDCALL attribute could be preventing linking if you are compiling for 32 bits.

Comment: @user5713492 I have added `VALUE` atribute on arguments `a,b` like this: `integer(C_INT),value::a,b`, however I wasn't able to figure out what you mean by adding it to `function add`. And where should I put `!GCC$ ATTRIBUTES STDCALL :: add` and `!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES STDCALL :: add`. I'm sorry for a stupid question.

Comment: Your code is full of Fortran 2003. Removed the nonsense 95 from the title.

Comment: So edited. I also needed to edit `functions.c` to make it fly. Now it compiles, links, and runs correctly.

Comment: @user5713492 I have tried the code in this form and it still yields the same error. Does it compile for you?

Comment: Yeah `g++ -c functions.cpp` `gfortran -c cinterface.f90` `gfortran main.f90 functions.o -omain` built me a `main.exe`. Make sure you changed `functions.cpp` as well `cinterface.f90`.

Comment: @user5713492 Oh, so there was a problem with the makefile as it does something different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are most of the way there. There are two things you need to address to make this work: linkage and argument passing conventions.

**Linkage**

As francescalus noted, the Fortran compiler doesn't understand how to parse a C/C++ header file. So your functions.h and cinclude.c files aren't going to be of any use in this example.

Don't throw away your functions.h yet, though. In it you declare the add function as:

```
extern "C"
{
    int __stdcall add(int x, int y);
}
```

The `extern "C"` is the important part. This tells g++ that the symbols in the following block of code aren't subject to all of the C++ [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling). You'll need the same surrounding the `add` definition in functions.cpp.

```
extern "C"
{
    int add(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

Once you've done that all you will need to link are functions.o, cinterface.o/mod, and main.o.

**Argument passing conventions**

The way `add` is declared the arguments `x` and `y` are passed to the function by value. That is the default behavior for C/C++ function arguments. Fortran, on the other hand, defaults to passing arguments to functions/subroutines by reference. In C++ this would look like `int add(int* x, int* y)`. There are two ways to address this problem.

The first option is to redefine your add function with integer pointers for the arguments and dereference them inside the function.

```
extern "C"
{
    int add(int* x, int* y)
    {
        return *x + *y;
    }
}
```

The second option (IMHO the preferred option) is to declare the Fortran interface to pass the arguments by value. They aren't being modified in the `add` function...why pass them by reference? If you choose this option, then your cinterface.f95 will need to contain the following declaration of `add`:

```
integer(C_INT) function add(a,b) bind(C,name="add")
    use,intrinsic::ISO_C_BINDING
    implicit none
    integer(C_INT),value::a,b
end function add
```

Note the additional `value` decoration on the variables `a` and `b`. No matter which option you go with, without it on my machine I get 8393540 printed out as the result of the `add` function call. After addressing the argument passing conventions I get 3 printed out as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, this does not solve the general problem with a c++ library that should be used from Fortran. I don't understand the structure of the `.cpp` files of the said library. Therefore I cannot link them one by one

Comment: Your question was "How can I make add function in Fortran work?" I hope you found at least some value in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

A build system can simplify this significantly (albeit at the cost of introducing a complex build system).  Assuming the directory layout in your question (although without the the `cinclude.c` since I don't see what purpose it serves)

```
$ tree
.
├── cinterface.f90
├── clib
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── functions.cpp
│   └── functions.h
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── main.f90
```

The contents of the The cmake files are

```
$ cat CMakeLists.txt 
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

project(cpp-add LANGUAGES C CXX Fortran)

add_subdirectory(clib)

add_executable(glue cinterface.f90 main.f90)
target_link_libraries(glue PUBLIC cpp-clib)
```

and

```
$ cat clib/CMakeLists.txt 
add_library(cpp-clib functions.cpp)
```

The project can then be configured and built in the usual way:

```
$ cmake -H. -Bbuild && cmake --build build
```

Execution:

```
$ build/glue
           3
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, can you show us the g++ compile line?

My issue was caused because my make file didn't properly include the appropriate .o file within the compilation for the .exe

i.e I had something like

```
Test: Test.cpp dependancy.o 
      g++ Test.cpp -o test.exe
```

and I was getting the same error returned that you did.

I solved it by ensuring the .o was actually used on the compile line.

```
Test: Test.cpp dependancy.o 
      g++ dependancy.o Test.cpp -o test.exe
```

I suggest this because the error "Undefined Symbol" typically means the compiler doesn't actually know where the code is for your call to the add function.